# Can ffmpeg be paused while recording, and then resume?

Tags: ffmpeg, shell-script

I want to record an FM radio station that provides an internet stream. I've worked out the command to record this, and I'm happy with the results. However, once in awhile I will start the command and I get this output:

```
Output #0, mp3, to '/Volumes/Linkstation/Audio/Radio Programs/test.m4a':
  Metadata:
    icy-br          : 64
    icy-name        : KXL-FM
    StreamTitle     : ad|main - Commercial Break -
```

Please note the "Commercial Break" metadata value. If I'm not mistaken, this value changes while the stream is live, and seems to be a reliable marker of when they've went to commercial break.

Can ffmpeg pause recording at all, and resume?

If so, can it do so programmatically from a shell script (and not just interactively like from a keypress)?

If so, can I somehow detect that the StreamTitle metadata has changed?

Comment: Try sending it a STOP signal when you want it to pause and a CONT when you want it to resume.

Comment: @Scott Any idea how the other parts of the question can be accomplished?

Comment: “Any idea …?”  Not in any detail, since I’ve never run ffmpeg and I know very little about it.  You say, “… once in a while I will start the command and I get this output …”  I guess that means when you start recording.  You say, “… this value changes while the stream is live …”  Can you observe it change while recording is in progress (i.e., other than by terminating the recording process and restarting it)?  Is there some ffmpeg command to show the status/metadata of an active recording process?  I guess it boils down to the last line of your question — “…can I somehow detect  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  that the StreamTitle metadata has changed?” — and I don’t know.  I suggest that you search (1) ffmpeg documentation, (2) [SU], and (3) the web.  And, if you can’t find anything, and you don’t get a good answer to this question after another day or two, post a new [SU] question, linking to this one, and emphasizing that the new question is focused on how to get the status of an active recording process.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  But, before you invest too much effort into that, you might want to try the STOP/CONT idea manually, to see whether it’s even worth pursuing.

Comment: @Scott I can't observe it change while in progress. But if I stop recording, and start again, I will see a different value. I have *some* idea how the metadata is embedded, and the stream periodically sends a new metadata chunk with an updated value.

Comment: Then I can't help you any more.  Good luck.